# Return type of template method in C++

Tags: c++, templates, debugging, syntax, syntax-error

I have these two `header` files, `List.h` and `ListTraits.h`
List.h inherits from `ListTraits.h`, and it is meant to be a template class implementation

of `std::list`. Now it all works fine but the `insert()` method implementation.
I am obliged to use `ListTraits.h`, in `List.h`, and while the `std::list insert` method returns

an `iterator`, the `ListTraits.h` method signature for `insert` is strange. These are the classes:

List.h

```
template <typename T> 
class List: public ListTraits<T> {
protected:
    std::list<T> list;
public:
    unsigned int size() {return 0;}

    ListTraits<T>& insert(const T& item) {     //<----------I think I should be returning iterator, but I have to return something of ListTraits<T> and that doesnt make sense
        typename std::list<T>::iterator it;
        list.insert(list.end(),  item);
        return it;
    }
    const T* getCurrentElement() const {
    
    }
    ...
```

And ListTraits.h

```
    #pragma once

//------------ Declarations for List traits used in Test1 in main.cpp
template <typename T> class ListTraits
{
    public:
        virtual unsigned int size() = 0;
        virtual ListTraits& insert(const T& item) = 0; //<-----------------------INSERT METHOD HERE---#######
        virtual void print() = 0;
};

//------------ Declarations for List traits used in Test2 in main.cpp
template <typename T> class ListTraitsExtended
{
    public:
        virtual const T* getCurrentElement() const = 0;
        virtual void advance() = 0;
        virtual void rewind() = 0;
};
```

Could you please help me complete the `insert` method so it is a templated version of the standard's libary `list.insert(it, value)` method?

Comment: What about simply returning `*this`? I believe that's what your teacher intended there.

Comment: `std::list`already is a template; there is no point in making a "templated version" of it. (This sounds like a misunderstanding of the popular exercise "implement a linked list, similar to `std::list`" as "implement a linked list by using `std::list`".)

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is not part of the question but  :::::::::           list.insert(list.end, & item);
         :::::::::::::::::::::::  gives error -----std::list<T,std::allocator<T>>::end': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member ---- and removing the & or using * instead, did not help

Comment: @c95 `end` is a function – you need to call it.

Comment: Aah, of course. Yes add (), and removed & and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @c95: for formatting code, use backquote \` to surround your code, instead of `:::`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
  return it;
}
```

to

```
  return *this;
}
```

this permits a technique known as "method chaining".

```
list.insert(a).insert(b).insert(c);
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. It works like that. I know its not part of the original question, but how would I return the current element from the     #####################        
             const T* getCurrentElement() const {}       method? #####################

Comment: @c95 If you have additional questions, use the [ask question] button not [add comment].